# ODBC w/Firedac and dbExpress Delphi Alexandria 11.3

Tags: sql-server, delphi, odbc, firedac, dbexpress

I have a situation where I am trying to get both dbexpress and firedac to connect using ODBC using an ini file.

The reason why we need to implement odbc vs mssql driver is because SQL Server apparently no longer accepts remote connections using the native client dll.

I managed to get dbexpress connection to work by putting this in my ini file. (Delphi version 10 seattle)
I am trying to get the connection to work on firedac (Delphi alexandria 11.3)
walking through the code, the connection string looks like this:
`Database=QCLocal;Server=PV06;DriverID=ODBC;DataSource=qcLocal13;MonitorBy=Remote;MARS=yes;OSAuthent=no;User_Name=ccm;Password=ccm`

But when it tries to connect, I get:

> Project LoginTest.exe raised exception class EODBCNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'.
> (qcLocal13 DOES exist and is spelled correctly)

Other settings/variances I have tried:
`Database=QCLocal;DriverID=ODBC;ODBCDriver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;DataSource=qcLocal13;MonitorBy=Remote;User_Name=ccm;Password=ccm`

`Database=QCLocal;DriverID=ODBC;ODBCDriver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;DataSource=qcLocal13;Server=PV06;MonitorBy=Remote;User_Name=ccm;Password=ccm`

`Database=QCLocal;DriverID=ODBC;ODBCDriver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=PV06;MonitorBy=Remote;User_Name=ccm;Password=ccm`

> (error Project LoginTest.exe raised exception class EODBCNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied'.)

`Database=QCLocal;DriverID=ODBC;Server=PV06;MonitorBy=Remote;User_Name=ccm;Password=ccm`

> Project LoginTest.exe raised exception class EODBCNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'.

My uses clause DOES include
FireDAC.Phys.ODBC, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCDef

So any ideas what I am missing and how to fix it?

Comment: The database client/driver support shipped with Delphi for DBExpress has not been updated in a long time. If you need to still use DBExpress I would suggest using devart's [dbExpress Driver for SQL Server](https://www.devart.com/dbx/sqlserver/) which has a 30-day trial available.

Comment: I understand that.  that's why I'm mid conversion to firedac/odbc.  but I am having issues trying to setup the odbc connection for firedac